# Kernel scheduling after local_irq_enable

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, scheduled-tasks, linux-device-driver, powerpc

In the below piece of kernel code, if there are interrupts or Exception between local_irq_enable(); and preempt_enable();. Will it result in  "Scheduling while atomic" log. 
Because once the interrupts are enabled, scheduler will be called and preemption is disabled.

PREEMPT_CONFIG is enabled and in power PC arch.

```
 static inline void __raw_spin_unlock_irq(raw_spinlock_t *lock)
    {
            spin_release(&lock->dep_map, 1, _RET_IP_);
            do_raw_spin_unlock(lock);
            local_irq_enable();
            preempt_enable();
    }
```

Comment: What is a question? What do you mean by `Exception` in the kernel space? Why scheduler will be called when preemption is disabled?

Comment: I was referring to Exceptions in PowerPC architecture. Yes, scheduler should not be called when preemption is disabled, but External interrupt exception had happened and the scheduler was called inside the softIRQ through sleep call. Hence i was seeing scheduling while atomic bug.

Comment: It is prohibited to call sleeping functions in softIRQ context.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue and one of the driver code was doing it.

Comment: @GuruswamyBasavaiah So, repeating Tsyvarev, what is the actual question?